# sockets in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, sockets

I'm using **gcc** for compiling and linking Objective-C programs, and I'm wondering if there is socket library that is unified, portable, and/or cross-platform (like Python's socket module).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[code.google.com/p/btlsocket/](http://code.google.com/p/btlsocket/)

Also read the documentation on NSSocketPort. You can take a look at [the examples here](http://macdevcenter.com/pub/a/mac/2006/11/14/how-to-write-a-cocoa-web-server.html).

Answer (score 1):

You’ve only specified gcc and Objective-C. Of course there are no sockets in both of them. What is your platform? What are common libraries or frameworks?

There are BSD sockets on Mac OS which are similar in nearly all Unicees.

Comment: I'm aware that they aren't built-ins. As I asked, I am wondering if there is "unified, portable, and/or cross-platform" library.

Comment: Cross platform? On mac you use gcc/objective-c so I assume you write code using cocoa frameworks ... on what other platform (apart from cocoa-touch) would you like to compile your objective-c/cocoa code with gcc?

Answer (score 1):

The BSD sockets are unified across most platforms, but if you want a Objective-C library which is easy to use, I found:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/smallsockets/